# Rigify mixing bones between DEF and ORG hierachies

Tags: unity, rigify, inverse-kinematics

I'm building a custom Rigify metarig with a spines.super_head. The final head bone has a number of (disconnected) child bones for the beak (which are a limbs.simple_tentacle), but once generated the DEF bones for these beak bones are not placed under the DEF bones of the head but rather under the ORG bones of the head, like so:

Rig

- ORG-neck1

  - ORG-neck2

    - ORG-head

      - DEF-beak
- DEF-neck1

  - DEF-neck2

    - DEF-head

While this works fine for animations made using the Rigify controls, it fails in-game because I need to apply runtime IK to the head... which leaves the beak floating off in space.

Currently I'm copying the transforms over after the IK runs, but this seems like a terrible kludge.

The above hierarchy is simplified from:

[image: the full hierarchy].